# If the important changes affect our use of Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, sdk

I received an email from Google Analytics, but I don't know if the changes will affect our use of Google Analytics?  Can you investigate if the below changes affect our use of Google Analytics?

Below is the content of the email：

> From: Google Analytics
>   Subject: Important changes to your Google Analytics for mobile apps properties
>
> Disclaimer: If you are an Analytics 360 account holder, your properties in the 360 account will not be impacted by the changes described here and you can disregard this message.
>
> Dear Google Analytics customer,
>   You are receiving this email because you have been identified as a user of the older style of Google Analytics mobile apps reporting and the Google Analytics Services SDK. Specifically, we are notifying you regarding your Google Analytics account(s) xxx xxx (1234567) and their properties listed below.
>
> We want to remind you that starting this October we will begin sunsetting this older style of Google Analytics for mobile apps reporting and the Google Analytics Services SDK. We are investing our resources in the latest style of app reporting in Google Analytics that works in conjunction with Firebase – Google’s integrated app developer platform. As such, the following will take place:
>
> Starting October, we will begin to decommission properties that were identified at the time of our first notice as receiving data exclusively from the Google Analytics Services SDK.
>
> - Data collection and processing for such properties will stop October 31, 2019.
> - Reporting access through our UI and API access will remain available for these properties’ historical data until January 31, 2020.
> - After our service is fully turned down in February, 2020, these properties will no longer be accessible via our Google Analytics UI or API, and their data will be removed from Google Analytics servers. You will receive further notification as these deadlines approach.
>
> We want to give you plenty of time to make the transition and start collecting new data using the Firebase SDK, since your historical data will no longer be available. Our latest solution, however, is even more intuitive and includes free and unlimited event reporting to meet the needs of app-centric businesses. We’ve invested heavily to make this solution best-in-class, with new features and capabilities, such as a more robust Audience builder and multi-dimensional report filtering, rolling-out continually. Additionally, our offering is closely integrated with other Google products and features to help grow your app business like Crashlytics, Google Ads, AdMob and Remote Config. For more information, visit the Help Center for an overview and list of available features.
>   Affected Properties: xxx App Production (UA-1234567-6).
>
> Thank you,
>   The Google Analytics Team

Comment: Not a programming question, so probably off-topic. But they are telling you that they will shut down some of your properties (since the Analytics SDK for mobile is phased put) and that you have to switch to Firebase for App Tracking, so yes, this will affect you.

Comment: I'm also looking for the answer of if the mobile app will stop working if we didn't get it switched over on time?